# Filtering the question page on tags shows no questions while it should

Tags: bug, question-lists, new-nav

When I click the filter *favorite tags* it often doesn't show anything. After a while, some new questions ping in, but the original list is empty:

> [image: empty question page]

There really should be questions on SO with those tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So this seems to be a bug after all and they actually fixed it (at least it says it was fixed, let's give it a try!).

From the [new nav update question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261307/245360):

> Tag engine performance! We are hitting a performance bottleneck with tag engine. This is why you sometimes see empty results (but see a list upon refresh) ...

Thanks team!

Comment: Has this fix been rolled out yet? I've just experienced this exact issue on a custom tab

Comment: It doesn't happen as often as it did. When do you experience this?

Comment: I have a custom tab with some favourite tags as the filter. It was happening regularly. It took maybe 6 or 7 refreshes to break it this time so maybe a slight improvement

Comment: It does seem much better actually. I think that first time was a fluke. It does still happen though with some persistant switching between tabs.

Comment: Okay. Caching might be the issue as described in the comments below.

Answer (score -3):

This is probably caching: consider that we only have 2000 users using the new nav, so you are going to hit empty caches much more often.

What happens if you refresh?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, why would it show empty? This is a user based cache, right?

Comment: Can you paste the permalink at the bottom of the list?

Comment: [Sure](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=new&show=all&sort=recentlyactive&page=1&pageSize=50&excerpts=compact&tagFilter=favorite&tags=.net%20asp.net%20c%23%20html%20html5%20invantive-composition%20javascript%20jquery%20oracle%20plsql%20sql%20sql-server&mode=any).

Comment: argh, what are your favorite tags?

Comment: .net asp.net c# html html5 invantive-composition javascript jquery oracle plsql sql sql-server

Comment: I see millions of questions there: it's probably caching

Comment: But why? Very often it is empty. That can't be by-design.

Comment: So the misses are a result of the nav alpha being on a test environment and not in production?

Comment: @tra if I am correct that is not the issue. The issue is the cache is empty and they don't await the result of the fetch.

Comment: We await up to 1.5 seconds, after that the server keeps on spinning but we return an empty page. The result is then cached.