# The search is *incorrectly* returning a *no results* message

Tags: bug, search, new-nav, 408-timeout

Steps to reproduce:

- Click on StackOverflow icon

  https://stackoverflow.com/
- Click on popular tab

  https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=popular&page=1&pageSize=15
- Click to sort by votes

  https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=popular&sort=votes&page=1&pageSize=15
- Click to show all time

  https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=popular&show=alltime&sort=votes&page=1&pageSize=15

I could manually reproduce that every time I tried.

The following is a print screen of the message shown after going through the steps:

[image: Sorry, that filter combination has no results. Please try different criteria.]

And if I subsequently do a <kbd>F5</kbd> refresh, it works.

And considering the fact that I clicked on *all time* option, it makes me think that what happened, actually, was a timeout.

If my guess is right, I think that [timeouts are currently being handled elsewhere differently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290369/1064325). So, while resolving the performance issue (therefore,  avoiding the timeout), a proper timeout message and a link to refresh the page would be a perfect fallback.

<sub>Note that it might not related to timeout - it was just a guess on the issue - it could, for example, be some weird caching problem due to current [alpha testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259220/284991). Anyway, it still seems to be a bug.</sub>

Comment: I'm seeing this periodically as well, although nothing I can reliable reproduce.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, repro here, Chrome 43+, Win 7.

Comment: Related or duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259311/filtering-the-question-page-on-tags-shows-no-questions-while-it-should