# Main page of SO is telling me there are no questions

Tags: bug, new-nav

I clicked on the logo for Stack Overflow to go back to the home page and it told me no questions were found. This also happens when I open a new tab and go to stackoverflow.com.

> [image]

My last view had been tags=WPF with the Needs Answer tab selected, so I know there are plenty of questions here.

I had noticed going back to the main page was being obnoxiously slow today, so suspect this is just a timeout instead of an actual problem with no results found.

Can you fix the slowness of going back to the main page of SO by clicking on the logo? Alternatively, perhaps load the default SO page if a timeout occurs retrieving the user's last used question filter.

(PS. I'm [in favor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259278/what-should-clicking-on-the-site-logo-questions-links-in-the-site-header-do#comment845526_259278) of having the logo go back to the default view of SO in all cases, with no filters applied. That would be my preferred "solution") :)

**Edit** 
I do not think this is an exact duplicate of [The search is *incorrectly* returning a *no results* message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259346/158605) because I obtained this message by going to StackOverflow's homepage, not by using search results. In addition, the only answer posted there is [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Having a message that there are no questions on the homepage seems like a bigger deal than encountering that message when searching, and additional code may be required to handle this correctly.

**Edit #2** 
I just went to stackoverflow.com from a new browser window, and got the same error screen.

I didn't realize my previous filter was cached and re-used when I visit the page in a separate session. This seems like something that should definitely be addressed if timeout issues are common.

Comment: Here is the same question over on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297688/website-new-navigation-thats-a-miss-error-on-initial-question-navigation)

Comment: It is a query that takes to long to execute. The page rendering pipeline doesn't wait for the results of the query...

Comment: Can you take a screenshot showing the URL address bar so that we can take a look at what params are passed

Comment: @HackerKarma Sure, it was in the original screenshot but someone edited it out. I've put the original screenshot back, which includes the url of *"stackoverflow.com"* (no parameters)

Comment: @HackerKarma there are no parameters, hence I didn't see any harm in removing it. (that's the expected URL from clicking the logo)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for editing but in this case its worth to keep it or else idiots like me ;) will keep asking... Jokes apart but this is totally weird... let me do some more investigation

Comment: @HackerKarma well, rene's comment makes much sense, that's the first thing the devs should check IMO. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes I agree with rene's comment and Rachel's Edit #2. Right now, Rachel can remove the cache/browser history for SO site links and that should load the SO main page with default settings... But, SE devs should think of a better solution for the case like this timeout

Comment: I'm not going to have a fight over the duplicate @Rachel , but the root-cause is similar. In both cases a search query is run which takes to long to run to completion. By the time it does, the train with the html response already left the station.

Comment: I find this occurs when using the default `new` which tends to automatically use the url `http://stackoverflow.com/?tagFilter=all`. **Please fix**. It wastes users time all the time.

Comment: It is often also accompanied by an error in my chrome console. `ados.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse` Which is at the very end of the ados.js file.