# Switching filter to "favorite tags" provides no results

Tags: bug, new-nav

I had been inactive on the homepage for a while - unsure of the exact time - and when I switched my filter from the default `recommended` to `favorite tags`, I received the "That's a miss" no results page.

[image: no results image]

Obviously, pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> resolves the problem and generates a list of questions with my favorite tags.

Comment: Duplicate of [Filtering the question page on tags shows no questions while it should](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259311/245360). Also, there is the 'official' answer to your question (which could use some down-votes in my opinion).